# How to select the nth() page of a document section with PDFreactor?

Tags: css-paged-media, pdf-reactor

I am evaluating PDFreactor to produce PDF from HTML & CSS.

However I have run into a problem - I need to set the page background image different for the 1st and 2nd and 3rd pages of a document section. The only way it seems to be possible (looking in the [PDFreactor manual](http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html)), is to explicitly give the fixed document page number, rather than a number that is relative to the document section.

[CSS Generated Content for Paged Media Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#document-sequence-selectors) suggests I would use this notation;

CSS:

```
@page:-nth(1 of PPSid1117) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
@page:-nth(2 of PPSid1117) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg2-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
@page:-nth(3 of PPSid1117) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg3-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#PPSid1117 {
    page: PPSid1117;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="PPSid1117">Up comes 10 pages of lorem ipsum, the first three pages having different backgrounds... etc etc ...end of section.</div>
```

But it does not work at all - it throws a parse error;

```
Parse error in resource "main_css.php?doc=50"
Encountered '1' at position 11 in rule '@page:-nth(1 of PPSid1117)
```

BTW, -ro-nth DOESN'T throw an error but still does not work - ie.

```
@page:-ro-nth(1 of PPSid1117) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

This code puts the it on every left page of the section (so it proves the named page selector works at a basic level) but is not what I want at all.

```
@page PPSid1117:left {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

This works but it means I have to hard-code the page number. Not what I want to do...

```
@page:-ro-nth(4) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

This puts it on page 1 of the document, not page 1 of the section.

```
@page PPSid1117:-ro-nth(1) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

This does what I want in Prince XML.

```
#PPSid1117 {
    page: PPSid1117;
    prince-page-group: start;
}

@page PPSid1117:nth(1) {
    background: url("http://example.com/bg1-section1.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Does anyone have any helpful suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set a background to the first, second and third page it is as simple as defining

```
@page :nth(1) {
    background: url(path/to/img) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

@page :nth(2) {
    background: url(path/to/img) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

@page :nth(3) {
    background: url(path/to/img) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

This definitely works with PrinceXML and if PDFReactor works with the W3C specs it should work too.

Comment: Thanks but as the question says, I want the nth page of a _document section_ not of the entire document.

What you propose can be done in PDFreactor by using the :-ro-nth() pseudo class, whereas using the :nth() pseudo class triggers a CSS parsing error. `Parse error in resource "main_css.php?publicationID=50"
    Encountered '4' at position 11 in rule '@page :nth(4) {`

Comment: Sorry, you have not answered the original question and you have not tested this in PDFreactor therefore this is not a useful answer.

Comment: I came back from 2019 and I can confirm this does not work. :/